# CiviRules - What does 'Compare with original value (before the change)' do?

Tags: civirules

There is a checkbox for the field value comparison that is *Compare with original value (before the change)?*

[image]

What functionality does this do? I looked at the docs (https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/basic-example-field-value-comparison-condition/) but didn't see an explanation.

My use case is I have a custom field that is a set of checkboxes. I am adding an activity based on a a specific custom field value being selected but I don't want it to do trigger my action (in this case an activity) each time the fieldset is saved if the value is already selected. I thought that this option may be checking if the field value changed but it still added the action.

FWIW, I created a regular group that the CiviRule adds them to. My condition checks *Not in Selected Group* [the group] to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comparison is pre-change. For example if I changed my surname from Smith to Jones and setup a condition to check surname = 'Smith' then setting this checkbox (Compare Original) would match to 'Smith' as that was my surname prior to the change I made. Hope that makes sense!

In terms of your use case - I think you've solved it the right way i.e. having a marker to indicate you've processed the contact already.

Comment: So then it may not be applicable for some fields? e.g, checkbox.

Comment: In theory it would still work i.e. you could check if the value prior to the change was checked/unchecked. But I think your approach is still the easiest to maintain and monitor.

Comment: It doesn't give you the option to say what a given checkbox value field should meet. Agreed though on this solution.

Comment: Ah ok, I guess its a work in progress!